# Reversing a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, reversing

I started doing the C++ challenges on coderbyte. The first one is:

> Using the C++ language, have the function FirstReverse(str) take the
>   str parameter being passed and return the string in reversed order.
>
> Use the Parameter Testing feature in the box below to test your code
>   with different arguments.

It gives u the follow starting code, which you then edit and add to to create the program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string FirstReverse(string str) { 

  // code goes here   
  return str; 

}

int main() { 

  // keep this function call here
  cout << FirstReverse(gets(stdin));
  return 0;

}
```

I have come up with the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string FirstReverse(string str) {
    cout<<"Enter some text: ";
    cin>>str;
    string reverseString;

    for(long i = str.size() - 1;i >= 0; --i){
        reverseString += str[i];
    }

    return reverseString;

}

int main() {

    // keep this function call here
    cout << FirstReverse(gets(stdin))<<endl;
    return 0;

}
```

It gives me the following error: "No matching function to call to gets"
Now, why does this happen and what can I do to fix it? Thank you for reading this and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Already available](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) in the standard library. An example implementation is provided too.

Comment: If you used `unsigned long` you would have greater range.  Never heard of a string with a negative length.

Comment: if you still want to build your own iterator_loop use reverse_iterators, see [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rbegin/)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I thought if the word was backwards the length was negative? `std::string("!tahw").length() == -5` :)

Comment: @Ben: str.size() as it is used in the example returns the unsigned type size_t (standard unsigned int). So it is alwaly positive

Comment: Proof that sarcasm rarely works on the Internet.

Comment: @user4581301 I almost believed it was possible. But i guess not.

Comment: Did not react fast enough to that, it is past midnight here... Also the smiley-face is hidden behind Ben's code example :P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`gets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets) method is declared in the `cstdio` header.

Try `#include <cstdio>` or `#include <stdio.h>`

**Edit 1: Use `std::string`**
I recommend using `std::string` and `std::getline`.

```
std::string text;
std::getline(cin, text);
std::cout << FirstReverse(text) << endl;
```